# What is the corresponding AWS EC2 level for this specification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We'd like to use AWS to build code.
Below is the specification for the build server, is there any corresponding hardware level for AWS EC2?

Ampere AC-1GB06A1S5 - Mt. Snow SATA DVT L6 2U Altra Server with:

1 x AC-108021002P Ampere AR< Altra processors

- 80 ARMv8.2-A
- 64-bit CPU cores
- 3.0GHz
- 8DDR4-3200 Memory Channels
- 128 PCIe Gen4 Lane

And installed:

- 16 x 16GB RDIMM 3200
- 1 x 4TB SATA 2.5" SSD
- Ubuntu

Or is there any other solution? Thanks.

Comment: I find anything less than a M5 8x large to be unusable for these workloads. Unfortunately you can only approximate what you need, due to everything in AWS (EC2 in particular) is throttled. So what works on normal hardware/hypervisors doesn't necessarily translate in AWS.  It's usually simpler to try one and upgrade if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fairly powerful ARM based machine. My best guess at an equivalent is [m7g.16xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/m7g/) which has 64 ARM cores and 256GB RAM. You could start a couple of instance sizes lower with a m7g.8xlarge which has 32 cores and 128GB RAM.

You can then likely switch to compute optimized if you need more CPU but less RAM, or memory optimized if you have enough CPU but need more RAM.